# TestNG @BeforeTest object initialization issue

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng

```java
public abstract class TestBase{

protected EnvironmentDetails envdetails;


@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "envOld", "envNew", "env", "region", "prodcount", "unixuser", "unixpasswd", "mmPortOld", "mmPortNew" })
public void initialize(@Optional("xyz4") String envOld, @Optional("xyz4") String envNew, @Optional("xyz4") String env, @Optional("All") String region,
            @Optional("5") String prodcount, @Optional("") String unixuser, @Optional("") String unixpasswd, @Optional("6300") String mmPortOld,
            @Optional("6300") String mmPortNew) throws SQLException {

               //Populate envdetails
               //LOG envdetails
            }

}

public class myTest extends TestBase{

@Test(threadPoolSize = 1, invocationCount = 1, groups = { "usersort", "regression" }, dataProvider = "sortingDataProvider")
public void sortTest(final String region, String mmUrl, String servletUrl) {
    //LOG envdetails
}


@DataProvider(name = "sortingDataProvider", parallel = false)
public Object[][] provider(Method method) {
     Object[][] data = null;
     //populate data
     return data;

    }
```

In the above code I initialized the object 'envdetails' in the **@BeforeTest**, when I log the object I find it correctly populated. Now, when I try to access it from the sortTest method each instance variable in the object **envdetails is null in one execution while shows populated in some other execution, keeping code base and execution parameter passed though maven untouched**. Is this some kind of threading issue or am I doing some major mistake.

Comment: can you check whether the initialize method is actually not throwing any error before initialization of envdetails.

Comment: Initialize method throwing up no exception. Its Logging envdetails perfectly, but as it moves to sortTest its Logging envdetails as `EnvironmentDetails [env=null, envOld=null, envNew=null, mmPort=null ...]`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've run on exactly the same issue.